# How do I change from a PR to a draft PR at github?

Tags: github, pull-request

Github release the [draft PR](https://github.blog/2019-02-14-introducing-draft-pull-requests/) a while ago.

I have a normal PR and I wanted to change that to a draft PR. How can I do that?

Comment: Given that you select that on creation, if you don't see anything in the PR UI, you probably can't.

Comment: As of April ~8th (2020) the option finally exists below the reviewers selection box.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

### Update - Now Available - Jan 2020

#### Convert Default → Draft

This is possible now, with an option below "Reviewers" section in PR.

[image: convert to draft screenshot]

See: [Feature Request: Switch from ready to draft in pull requests](https://github.community/t/feature-request-switch-from-ready-to-draft-in-pull-requests/1749/63)

#### Convert Draft → Default

To answer [@marsandback](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4378314/marsandback) comment Draft PR --> PR, just click the Ready for review

[image: draft screenshot]

Comment: Ultimately, how does the PR get un-drafted? All reviewers approving? Can the draft mode be reverted?

Comment: I would put the correct answer on top as an edit and leave the original answer below. We are not talking about a stand-alone software that can still be used in its previous form.

Comment: @MarsAndBack always via "ready for review". It can always be reverted. Of course companies' policies may vary a lot but, generally speaking, reviewers should not review a draft.

Comment: Note that a screen refresh need to be done manually  to see the change

Comment: Note that this is only available on public repositories

Answer (score 13):

The feature is now available!

**See**: [Feature Request: Switch from ready to draft in pull requests](https://github.community/t/feature-request-switch-from-ready-to-draft-in-pull-requests/1749/63)

Comment: Hmm, is this released? I am not able to see the "Convert to draft" in Reviewers section...

Answer (score 6):

You can't change now, but you can follow the feature request from GitHub Community:

[Feature Request Switch from ready to draft in pull requests](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Feature-Request-Switch-from-ready-to-draft-in-pull-requests/td-p/19107)

Answer (score 5):

Although as this answer is created you currently can't change the stage of a normal pull request into a draft. However, You can prefix the pull request with `[WIP]`  e.g:

```
[WIP] Allow changing stage of an open pull request to draft.
```

It is pretty common in open source to claim an issue this way.

Check contributing guidelines on the repository, in case they have specific guidelines to follow.

Here is mediawiki guidelines for code contribution

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Developer_Wishlist/2017/Code_Contribution_(Process,_Guidelines,_etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As it's been pointed out, this is possible by going to the pull request itself. Under the reviewers section on the right, look for the text: *"Still in progress? Convert to draft"*, where "*convert to draft*" is a hyperlink. Click on it, confirm, and it's done.

See screenshot in the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/changing-the-stage-of-a-pull-request#converting-a-pull-request-to-a-draft).

Answer (score 0):

Can convert to draft under the reviewers section.

[image]

Comment: Although I have seen that option before, I don't always have that option after I've created a PR.